# Cannot boot into the bootable USB stick on Lenovo G470

Tags: boot, live-usb, lenovo

I want to help my sister to move from Windows 7 to Linux Ubuntu 14.04.1. When I boot the computer into the bootable USB stick, it just show me :

[image]

------------------------------------------------↓ Then ↓------------------------------------------------

```
Black background with a underline sign winking
_________________________________________
| _                                     |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
_________________________________________
```

I have tested for Ubuntu 14.04 also, I encounter the same problem. =[ 
I wonder if Ubuntu 14.04.1 do not support the hardware of Lenovo G470.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me when I was trying to do the same. Try opening the boot settings and change it so the usb is the first thing the computer goes to boot instead of windows.

Comment: But this(http://i.stack.imgur.com/qG1Su.png) had been shown.